# GoogleMap перемещение маркера

Tags: google-maps-api

Доброй ночи всем, столкнулся с проблемой: что сейчас я вывожу маркеры с помощью google maps на нужной мне позиции
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': '{pos_x}, {pos_y}' } )
    .click(function (e) {$('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': "User: {id}" }, this);});

У меня раз в 5 секунд кидается Ajax запрос в базу данных, где цепляется новое место положение маркера, и я возвращаю так-же pos_x, pos_y, id. А теперь сам вопрос, как мне без перезагрузки страницы перемещать маркеры, удалять их и заново делать им Spawn или есть другие методы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setPosition()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)?